# Bootstrap 3: Push/pull columns only on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout on a page:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">4</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">5</div>

 --------- ----- ----- ----- ---------
|    1    |  2  |  3  |  4  |    5    |
 --------- ----- ----- ----- ---------
```

But on smaller screen sizes I would like the following layout:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">5</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">4</div>

 ----------------- -----------------
|        1        |        5        |
 ----------------- -----------------
|     2     |     3     |     4     |
 ----------- ----------- -----------
```

(Note the re-arranging of the column order.) Is it possible to push/pull columns only on smaller screen sizes? I've tried the following, but I get the oddest layout, and seem to lose `<div>5</div>` completely...:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4>3</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4>4</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-12">5</div>
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Answered it myself, simply by thinking: mobile first!

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-lg-push-6">5</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4 col-lg-pull-3">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4 col-lg-pull-3">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4 col-lg-pull-3">4</div>
```

Get them in the order I want on the tablet first, then push/pull them in to position on the desktop.

Comment: Yep, that's the right way to do it, since Bootstrap (3) **[is itself mobile-first](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)**.

Comment: Today I learn my lesson with boostrap... **Think mobile first**. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had a slightly different requirement (still in the similar lines)

the below gets me there:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">TIME</div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-6">EVENT</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4">STATUS</div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 visible-xs"></div> @*offset for xs*@

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6">START LIST</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-4">RESULTS</div>
</div>
```