# change Bootstrap DIV order depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Scenario: I have an editor widget (think textarea) for a renderable template, a preview panel for the edited template, and a list of error messages generated when rendering the preview. My intended layout is like this:

```
small screen:            large screen:

+--------------+         +--------------+ +--------------+
|              |         |              | |              |
|    editor    |         |    editor    | |    preview   |
|              |         |              | |              |
+--------------+         +--------------+ +--------------+
|              |         +-------------------------------+
|    errors    |         |                               |
|              |         |            errors             |
+--------------+         |                               |
|              |         +-------------------------------+
|   preview    |         
|              |
+--------------+
```

I only need those two layouts (not three or four), as only -lg is large enough to make sense for the editor and preview to be next to each other. To control the sizes, I added col-xs-12 to all three DIVs and col-lg-6 to the editor and preview (the error list should stay at 12 on large screens).

Other posts about the topic have suggested that the "smallest" layout dictates the order of the DIVs in the HTML, so that would be: editor, errors, preview. They further tell to change the order on large screens with -pull- and -push- classes. I tried doing that by adding col-lg-pull-6 to the preview and col-lg-push-6 to the errors. As far as I understand, push/pull work relative to the current position of the elements, so that should have pulled the preview back into the first row, and pushed the errors box into the second row.

Note that I didn't use the "row" classes as I don't fully understand *how* to use them; the placement of elements into rows should depend on the screen size, not fixed by the HTML (that's the whole point of a responsive layout, isn't it?)

Other posts have also suggested to render one of the boxes *twice*, making one of them invisible depending on screen size, but they lack thorough explanation why this is a good idea. This is purely a layout issue, and again the whole point of a responsive layout is so I don't have to mess up the HTML to adapt to screen sizes.

Comment: I am not expert with Bootstrap; so I can't give you Bootstrap solution; but if you use okay to use custom CSS you may use `Flex` Method and its far more easier to get a desire layout. The main feature of `Flex` is at any time you can change the display order of divs.

Comment: Unless you use Flexbox, there is no CSS solution. The push, pull, and offsets that come with Bootstrap work horizontally based on relative positioning plus or minus left or right. You can clone and append with jQuery or use server side to serve up different html to touch devices that meet your width requirements or you can hide and show with the responsive utilities

Comment: Responsive design is to present, not adapt, the html as it is but adjusted via css to accommodate the view port. Adaptive design, using server side tools, can serve up different html based on the device. Without Flex, you can use css to hide and show and/or jQuery to clone and append. If you know the width and height of the editor and the preview you can use absolute positioning to make it look like it's below and use bottom padding on the container to keep it open. You can use jQuery to write the height and positioning on load and resize. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: can you please reproduce the problem in a fiddle to help us understand the structure?

Comment: are you okay with jquery solution? it seems there is no css solution.

Comment: BootstrapThemer: Wouldn't using jQuery to clone and append be manipulating the HTML? I started with the assumption that RD is about presentation, not manipulation, which is why I'm aiming at a pure CSS solution (my task at hand is, after all, about the presentation of the three areas).

Comment: Zafarbek: How a jQuery solution would work technically is obvious to me, so the question is either how to do it in CSS, or why doing it in CSS is a bad idea (the latter being, for example, an explanation telling me that placing the three areas on screen is NOT purely a presentation problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your question you mention using rows. The `.row` clears the column floats and adjusts the left and right margins of the columns so that there is not extra padding on the outside, not using the `.row` will mess up your layout. Here's a very comprehensive guide to the Bootstrap grid: **http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works**.

Using Flexbox is the only way to do it in pure css. To address older browsers (including less than or equal to ie9), I use Modernizr (the one in this demo link adds `.flexbox` or `.no-flexbox` on the html element, it's just for this demo. In this way, you can isolate your use of the flex model on browsers that support it and your fallback will be the standard bootstrap columns you set in your html. Don't forget to follow the grid instructions on GetBootstrap.com. You will need to make your own build of Modernizr.

To get Bootstrap.css to work on IE8, you need to use Respond.js -- see their docs and link up the CSS locally with relative path. Use jQuery 1 series, greater than 1.10 though 1.9 works. jQuery 2 is not supported in older IE 8 browsers.

[image]

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/dimuq/1

---

### SMALL VIEW PORT:

[image]

### LARGE VIEW PORT:

[image]

#### CSS:

```
/* uses Modernizr to add .flexbox to html class, if not supported the fallback are the basic bootstrap grid */
@media (min-width:992px) { /* choose your min-width this is using the md- default */
  .flexbox .flex-row.row {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

  .flexbox .flex-row [class*=flexcol-] {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
  
  .flexbox .flex-row .flexcol-editor, 
  .flexbox .flex-row .flexcol-preview {width:50%;}


  .flexbox .flex-row .panel {
        width: 100%;
        /*something to keep it open and add some inner style */
    }

  .flexbox .flex-row .flexcol-errors {
        order: 2;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

*Learn more about Flexbox here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
and http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/*

---

#### HTML -- requires Modernizr to check for flexbox and add class flexbox to the html (see demo js panel)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-row row">
      <div class="col-md-6 flexcol-editor">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">Editor</div>
         <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6 flexcol-errors">
      
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">Errors</div>
         <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et.</div>
        </div>
  
      </div>
      
    
      <div class="col-md-12 flexcol-preview clearfix">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">Preview</div>
         <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: For now, flexbox looks like "the right way" to me. I'll have a detailed look at it ASAP.

Comment: Works as expected and "feels right" too, so here's your bounty. For those trying the demo: You'll have to tweak the width or margin to fit the editor and preview into a single row. Browser support might be an issue for me, and makes me wonder if I can actually use flexbox in production yet, but then browser support wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    editor 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    errors 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    preview  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    errors 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: As already said in the question, I don't see why this is a good idea. I want to control the layout of one error box, not add a second one. I'll also have to make sure that the contents of the two error boxes stay in sync, both when first rendering the page and when adding errors to the boxes via Javascript. Please include an explanation why this is preferred to a pure CSS solution, since I'm under the impression that Bootstrap absolutely favors pure CSS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933664/bootstrap-3-push-pull-columns-only-on-smaller-screen-sizes) to help you on this.

Working with Bootstrap on a daily basis and for me this is working good. To make something more "radical" could set you in a position where by you should re-build the base CSS code to fit your needs.

Another solution would be to use jQuery to **append** or **prepend** these divs when turning to mobile. Hopefully some of this helps you!

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem is more complex because I don't want just a single row on desktop. I've already tried push/pull but I was unable to solve the problem using that.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a fun solution for you: [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/hRCKzeE25p). This incorporates using the `pull-right` class to move the preview column on a large viewport, then changing `marginTop` (to move the div up) the combined height of the other 2 divs. this lands it in the exact place you want.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div id="editor" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6" style="background-color:red;">editor</div>
    <div id="errors" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:blue;">errors</div>
    <div id="preview" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 pull-right" style="background-color:green;">preview</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
    var h=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    h=document.getElementById("errors").offsetHeight + document.getElementById("editor").offsetHeight;

  $("#preview").css("marginTop", "-="+h);
});
```

**Large viewport:**

[image: large viewport custom]

Now the problem with this solution right now is when you move to the small viewport, `preview` overlaps `editor`, so if you use the same height variable and do the opposite movement ( `marginTop: "+=" +h`) to it on the smaller viewport, it'll be put back in place.

The main benefit of this solution is avoiding multiple of the *exact same divs*

Comment: Thanks, but it's already clear to me how a jQuery solution would technically work. What I'm missing is why it is superior to pure CSS in solving what seems like purely a presentation issue to me.

Comment: @MartinGeisse Do you want duplication of divs or do you want one div with jQuery manipulating the position of the div. It's personal preference.

Comment: @MartinGeisse there are arguments to each side of jQuery and CSS solving this problem. If your duplicated divs is too complex and you have to change something - you have to change it twice.

Comment: @Charles Smartt neither makes sense to me, compared to placing the DIV in CSS.

Comment: @JordanD yes, that's exactly why I'm trying to avoid duplicate DIVs and why I'm aiming at placing the DIV by CSS. About jQuery vs. CSS: I think either is better than duplicate DIVs. If the CSS solution is based on flexbox, as suggested above, then the main argument pro jQuery is browser compatibility.

Comment: CSS and JavaScript both have compatibility problems across different browsers. It all depends on what you want to support. If you're trying to support IE8, JQuery is probably more viable (older versions) than CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the editor and the preview to be a fixed height in the desktop view, it's pretty easy to do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="editor">
        editor.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="errors">
    errors.
  </div>
  <div class="preview">
    preview.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {position: relative;}

.editor {height: 200px; overflow: auto; background: #eee;}
.errors {min-height: 100px; margin: 15px 0; background: #eee;}
.preview {min-height: 100px; background: #ddd;}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .preview {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 15px; width: 575px; height: 200px; }
}
```

**Demo**

http://www.bootply.com/4jpGHUJWzp