# switch column using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three columns whose order and size I want to be different depending on the screen size.
On desktop

```
----------------
|1      |2     |
--------|2     |
|3      |2     |
```

On mobile

```
---------------
|1            |
---------------
|2            |
---------------
|3            |
```

I've try but I can't get the desktop screen size to work properly.
here my code:
http://jsbin.com/yuyopowico/edit?html,css,output

Many thanks in advance

Comment: i do not see you include bootstrap.css, as soon as i include it, it works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933664/bootstrap-3-push-pull-columns-only-on-smaller-screen-sizes Check It out Bro...