# how to re-arrange divs

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="pimage clr">
    <img src="./images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">Onet</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pvideo">
    <img src="./images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pimage">
    <img src="./images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in larger display  i want this to display in the same order, but for tablet i want to display one and three together and two below them.

Comment: You can use flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Either [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) will do the trick alongside with [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

__Resources__

 - [Learn Grid](http://cssgridgarden.com/)
 - [Learn Flex](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use css flexbox

```
.item {
  order: <integer>; /* default is 0 */
}
```

It good to understand the concept, so please check the links below.
[csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[w3school flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid and use `pull` and `push` methods. Here is the sample example how it will work. First order your block as per the tablet device and then try to arrange the order for large device.

Initially |A|B|C| then we are going to change the order |A|C| and then below |B|

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
           Content A
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-4">
           Content C
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-4">
           Content B
       </div>
  </div>
```

If you seen the above code, I am pushing my `Content C` block to push right side and then `Content B` block to pull left side. Initially I have ordered it as per my desired screen then I moved the blocks accordingly for small screens.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2cJS/1752/)

Read the below SO Question for more clarity.

[Bootstrap 3: Push/pull columns only on smaller screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933664/bootstrap-3-push-pull-columns-only-on-smaller-screen-sizes)

Answer (score -1):

Usually element written in the fashion in html appears in the same order. So if you want to change the order of elements , you can either use duplicates and hide the one not requried.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pimage clr">
        <img src="./images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="text">Onet</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pvideo hide-sm">
        <img src="./images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="text">two</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pimage">
        <img src="./images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="text">three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="pvideo hidden show-sm">
        <img src="./images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="text">two</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`

> Add this style to hide/show when the screen size changes

```
    <style>
        .hidden{
    visibility:hidden;
    }
//change the max-width accordingly

    @media(max-width:400px){
        .show-xs{
        visibility:visible;
        }
    .hide-sm{
        visibility:hidden;
        }
    }
    .hidden{
       visibility:hidden;
    }
    </style>
```